# datadog facet path with special symbols

Tags: regex, regex-negation, grok, datadog

I have an index created on the log and the paths have special character :
**for example:**

```
@params.rs:orgId
@params.rs:format
```

**Sample URL:**

```
10.32.45.56 - user [12/Sep/2020:06:25:51 -0400] "GET /v1/resources/manifestinfo?rs:format=json&rs:orgId=123&rs:correlationId=39e8f697-3549-a142-224b-251fc6672a94-32edb97dc3f8 HTTP/1.1" 200 14002 - -
```

**grok parser:**

```
rule1 %{ipv4:network.client.ip}\s+-\s+%{word:user}\s+\[%{date("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"):date}\]\s+\"%{word:http.module}\s+\/v1\/resources\/+%{word:onemds.module}\?+%{data:onemds.params:keyvalue("=","/:","","&")}
```

when I try to add facet for `@params.rs:orgId`

I am getting error as

> An error occurred while saving the facet: The Facet path must contain
> only letters, digits, or the characters - _ . @ $

Answer (score 0):

got this resolved with below

rule1 `%{ipv4:network.client.ip}\s+-\s+%{word:user}\s+\[%{date("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"):date}\]\s+\"%{word:http.module}\s+\/v1\/resources\/+%{word:onemds.module}\?+%{data:onemds.params:keyvalue("=","/:","",":&")}`

was never expecting the delimiter that can take 2 characters above `:&`

this helped to remove **rs:** for all except the first one. not an elegant approach but it worked for my use case.